# Error when converting decoded zip file to .txt file using panda (decoded file missing '\t' at start)

Tags: python

```
import gzip
input_file = open("example.bed","rb")#compress existing file
data = input_file.read()

with gzip.open("example.bed.gz", "wb") as filez:
filez.write(data)
filez.close()
fileopen= gzip.open("example.bed.gz", "r+") 
output=fileopen.read()

decode=output.decode("utf-8")
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(decode, delimiter='\t',header=1 )#Works partially, missing '\t' at start of file throws error
df.to_csv('exampleziptotxt.bed', index=False)
```

Converting gzipped `.bed` file to `.txt` file using pandas. The start of the file is `chr8\t..`. because there is no leading `\t` the FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File chr8 is returned. Any advice how to correct input file so that it includes leading `\t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_csv()` accepts either a filename or a file-like object.

You're passing it the content of your file as a string, which it attempts to interpret as a filename, trying to open something called `chr8`, and fails.

Instead just pass the gzip file handle to the function (as it's a file-like object):

```
import pandas as pd

with gzip.open("example.bed.gz", "r+") as fileopen:
    df = pd.read_csv(fileopen, delimiter="\t", header=1)
```